# Strange behaviour with ember.js embedded content

Tags: ember.js

I have a strange bug that is causing me to scratch my head.

I have an Ember.State where I new up a controller each time it is entered:

```
  show: Ember.State.extend({
    enter: function(manager, transition) {
      this._super(manager, transition);

      var contact = App.store.find(App.Contact, App.appController.get('params'));

      App.set('selectedContactController', App.SelectedContactController.create({}));

      //TODO: Why do I have to do this when I have just called create?
      if(App.getPath('selectedContactController.content') && App.getPath('selectedContactController.content.length') > 0){
        App.setPath('selectedContactController.content', Ember.A());
      }
```

In another part of the code, I set the controller's content to an array that is loaded from the data store.

I have put a comment above the line I am writing this question about.  I have to clear the content collection even if I call create.  This has confused me.

The SelectedContactController looks like this:

```
App.SelectedContactController = Ember.ArrayProxy.extend(App.FeedScroller, {
```

The content property comes from the App.FeedScroller mixin that looks like this:

```
App.FeedScroller = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.Evented, {
  content: Ember.A(),
```

Anybody any idea why the content property does not get destroyed when create({}) is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

> App.SelectedContactController.create({})

You are still inheriting the default properties, some of which come from the mixin in the prototype chain.

If you don't want those default properties in the instance you create, you'll have to explicitly pass them as **null**

> App.SelectedContactController.create({content:null})

Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lifeinafolder/ag2Nb/

Hope this helps.